# Control Video input/ Visualization with Volume and BPM

Tags: audio, max, visualization, max-msp-jitter

i build something like automatic VJ program . I have 2 incomig videos signals from 2 webcams and a couple of visualisations(at the moment 2 but i want more). I have a volume in dB of incoming audio signal and bpm of it as a nummbers. What I need is a routing/switchig of video output. For example: if am bpm number changes more then 20-30 bpm then changes a a visualisation or a webcam from first to second. And the same with volume. I would be happy about a quick and dirty solution, please.
Can someone halp me? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you start your patch, you can select it all, go to Edit in the Menu bar at the top, the click Copy Compressed, then you can post the text here. Otherwise question is too vague for Stack.

Comment: its not so simple. My visualisations are in another patchers. But ill copy that later. i just want to know , what opotunitys i have... my videoinputs are in umenu and not 2 qmetros. how can i switch between them?

Comment: ok, if thats your specific question update your question to "I have video inputs in 2 umenus, how do i switch between them" then upload what you've tried or at least a sample of what your patch looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
7461.3oc6cktjiibb92ihPuCvcr+XkTOXq6CaMJ1iPgB8CYYGirb3XshIPSB
1M1EjfKH3LyJIOOM9MwuXtN.AAXCBTfDE.mQ6HscSV.jcUeHyrxLq73u8y+Y
u3tGxde7t6B9mC91fW7h+lZjWXFSOxKNLvKtacz6WjFsybi2sKMYYb9c2Wds
2FkuIZcbaWZaTwhmR173axiWTX+ivjjPBiBIx6CnHRn.hQXz8APfLDbe.hFB
B9KG976J9wT6Wb0WY19hz3hhebar866t6Nd6aixUSjh372DuI5A6mDd3ha1u
NYi5itqwnqRyhJTema2WzX7r7j3MEQEIYaN8awNCZ90jrzLKyd36dIlUMW2k
7WsyA0J6vPQuMd4ahJJxSdXeQ7wWsqDwO.4ZbMceb1pCiWcg5qyzrMOdFvuw
8s6or7BWtwC.KtsKlr4sI6RN.rk2v+yO+mYe0gWT9a0ut2YRJMLrOoB3Jhee
wadWxxhmzWkgNhesQQwngxCTTbbHDQfD1QJJ7UPQcFhlrMEUOawGmb5Ug469
8qhVFeW8auB6+p7jnz6F.4D8tKFU2D+N0WQCT0L92kTD1bJ1Crx.7Ph.xDFl
VCpxFJpp9i9l0QJp82e28mGiQshw0H.bFLQs.lPjmPyrsAeo5+9U5+WWfpD.
znGQPBYb.WSlJYSBd5B3PtbvQCBaeWxlkYuqq0ODAfgT0hFiT..gxfpkNQKe
TwH0fQ84bkMWkOjkqjgsHKMK2dCfPNkIX36UuRQzBP0dAr92b67zayi2cPhe
8IL.adfYXyUOkLD+vlOs5GZkD+P18Xdz1mB9xkIqCvHfFccA7EDhA70XN0mD
evAfPWAiYQ1iOlF6xJmQkkqbklG.6OG1BOYSQOJb.FBTzlDeIa7IV9A0rLOK
.4BHwUz5VPhJtLpiGh173.EH0JPH8CWyB8Z+CNAER4UBEiNiBDftBTY+5G5V
8b0l..CmBmeXka1wBgFrVT2+LBgqlcoc.Qb2Xo2Yq.hRARMo.sRn4EiH88zu
R+w0Y0zMqeFEHD3UH.K3VHPLcPvJMohQAvgfC7IAGpjJ.EhaMRADX7EZ96WE
7YIvfeyqz+5WoTz3u+2MC7qMC7R0.EOEuI.FDmtKNnacPvJKznPFGQTBYPhP
IASIH8VwxKSB6.ko1JnAf9UlJzniOVw0fgXjDe6KUUdE6xrHa8ZkpzOmNZWx
iahRCVEkltK3g3zr2oHbT5c+TV5xd.PbHxrWD1XGJUVICBJ5ABcvDdvEXdIn
EPCcMLe8gZ4I6h2ED8P1aicD0fLhA0HLg52LAlcihZWA22C6KJx1zMLvkOi3
AYY+.iolsCPfCBg76RFdXIitcVx3weiIkkewKeraS+fTnkK.yqvBB+xr9yfE
26Hlb0LKnVgwqvUBqRyT+EbRRKAPpPK5ER4LN6UcAv3prbkMWFWGODj0C9F7
2Dn1x2MxyZ.NFOFNm379UcUzhlH+USp1NG+U3HCCQxG5QHmw4UXtnB3D1M2F
rG+MmBznHji6UEIIRiRxTA139XN6.yoRd+rybJGKmzKEiOiXd19MKcBaIhJr
ESF2CPBc4vVSGceese.Ouqna0VmqwqZNn5QILRPzpS3.JbRkSuo4A3JzJWS.
cxp9IiXV009lzjEeePQVvt3hfh30ayZP2oTTu94SXOji5+33Ryb6aZBGsAtT
hwWTXAMDxw.ol+W5zly0OdilGzcqmyx8mtYREizeJZ6cWg.iybLKHfwBYkLc
ypQ770T88spO42tuv3hj5+osvoiXeZ7iQK9Q8Go5CzqtGFoIwKOc38JBgSev
W8c8vimeBoXj0GT043iwsRUCaPs0P.AhJDZGrz1qZr3Uy3GdrFTUa11..Ueb
NgBa9MRf5Cbq7ab7s6sHZ6IbUspvpDZ0BfEhPRJU6aE93YhKASYL43Xm6U44
9yruVxpfOaE727JboO3Tuwoc4fzpc4jhKSaSeX.znsMGB3AyM+m9h.FP8uPm
1Ar1Y7WZAEYT0KEcafyd3nsKRV6lhvD5QsLtTilrX7fCIEOhysZcJ3JrNMM4
swgOFkr4CsFzdsb4Nr2BIURZwXtTe9GVmJgEcF4FVGXpg3iuR+eUHeZxthKJ
L9P8E8F13an7WswE5Vb9QaSQZt3Xf98T16N.m9JT+Lw6hYQCtuuHA73SzuE9
WbHf.eNEPqAEXq+gWqddnu3K4GYIN4FhLTmr1ubxljBEKSKOqa61rOW05zW8
LrwssWcaUb8jwLDEWGuaWTMeMdz+7Js++rt20kYObKkNJDABp0dhHl.SKqGa
hOkrbY7lms+7E6cGn.b2rfkT1mfXIbdvRBm7oGV5iStbad1x8Kzm+Vfdypfr
UAKxhWsJYgd6icAqxx05eG7PxOrOZ4GBTyDEJGz8IgSr9ujBCkJzGpTJ.ira
wBudSWvizoyAE3yamIE.kLiUgO+UWmUgmkpVsIi5eDbf8EBVP0HuTAjRBhvU
CodAA2sm2wVsBvnZ3OCLwj+WIsNwGm2rRtw+dfhf90cumF9PHLnQOjRCbtMT
Y6yUTOr+AGyMigiY1u6cIVGBgFBYN0qmqVoF.ZGbIKE0RoWHs13erZX+crZP
Ayq.ao5.+iHvx8JvR3OGX4+iAvdEm+zpjT0hxDW9sarcq2PGaOAUBNzJmoyQ
txsmfzAmjbFKrqaxcGu3v8dog5tnyiZtI9yaE+kG2CzBWMIDTaPYGtTMDEhX
9+.y+2lOMJM.PLgIR+CIJURHF+t.N6O7gCr0ajtXeQ1pU5cSWntm37fU4w+P
0sllrIdQ1d64Ig5jajpyFKHkHLmuMjfMJYID137g9Q4dtRfmTeQ6Jid10.oO
HsZJuXOGsORUdQB8DPZ4yBxi2sMayttCzJLjcBlBsm76GqfpOLjbQZbTdkYh
IqNfvOjl8tcA62dAhFfRaXdBUZBIoLtA4sNlcVQdWfXrG76gAh61S1XolREx
4gHozjgqD7GUF9cMITX7ecYzhZ5djmUjoWQUylmhS2pHK6laGPQ1sdfTSPsq
0OgX7lDouifIMag0QtvgjgXsS.4gX1qj4zoyBAKTB6XXBVo2gMun4CkBp7LQ
NCcDyyzQr67SN6Kvcly9GztUJp77nv58.lWNF5ti3w1Rg+3k5L2qdx2btiJp
im.JJ8uen4hhjecYg8ps6dr67XhCC4RIhKzDvfPkgdbF+PvShYWh0civCgQK
G+wReCfJEcvDNlpyELlhNliwLxmP.nvC6J+1kwuMYQbumTF2RapqK.JIpbJf
qSfe1HmmcCHKjg3qfgbuRKv8USujh30k0Zm69Od8W+x+rRqzrGiy++9eMFbe
u9GlwB9Oie3ahV2v76VLhQdDqnfPNBSf5DipbuIzkD932+LxwqN8xvsBp9Hr
QB5U0OD5H8UKp+MXVW6evQHCDwdHbk1lGqzpaYPzV8ublsCnHqvPgPTEZXyR
NYh8QzxUzSbEwZm7.wmQb.5knguHNPKR15ruNPDgvXpjhAAQHTohnP.uPvXj
JSMXf2KSM0zPBR4gT.ExUp3yIgR8+zaHABEBBRhcuh0bwE3.Hym0FEk4ZUZC
pzqQHIra65iBDR7hWCx5w+VTZkrAkXBHCw0ghub9TLA4Cumjo1qnaC+ksAC7
YDFfyS8xoFiCSqoJGIIydMyAB8TQyY460UapGB9x8aR9g8wAPGgFHfExDTtT
ukZoTkafpnCT3Am6pTtuCPQWsKw..QGy808UKh4TF73xRsUej4gE5e30+aAe
09kIYAuNae9h3tK4cPEAfTRz5VJ35LpfpOMtCkmQestwdXc+Uq2llTreYbve
JOZw2mnyF7t3B.gDI.K35P5hV4nEHD40UtOBJne6pU5.Z60E4wadr3oK3XJ.
zPDGIv5cKvzPgjRYxCwT.l3IrX7B9j5GherAM1sHJsayMUVnSTaPpquM0WyX
1bV7WThQ0yb6sFJ6HVITe5j0JHvbifgTRtF+8f9kAvNS6FjLTnLcEh0vKJDq
nz.hprBg4mLuwk8i8.yXVmDcD89LTIVqWljFBXXIGYCpTetMiWCyKrZ+RLkX
RuOLiExwXt1LEF7FjSRs1Nv1.q6S1Qi+B4AWiX.837fkec762Fsomp3cimG0
jrAg7qge69dX7vC.iNI3esQKTirtQeFmuMNe2IGnyKtKZ61ZieRF4rN56rA.
M+X9mnlh1wpkgK4w5hk8Ie0pu6bEVVn.x84VL48LRsjtQehS4a1mbRE1tZp0
XCUaBDKo1zMzdh+v5L3573UeFT1TUtZxYLxKYyo4D9wquLdUz9zh2blyWn4M
b5oRz7pseLDu3tGySVlswXsYCrWO9g+jZitsA7Vi0j4V1DsssOtMv6O2U2oV
r628PTds5XNp5pEYYoMu1wOYZ7phxquMYylSAzhrscb07jGepqO8CYpqttyu
dyk18l8arW9MJ94h2nyvrStwnzzRN7FSekPgHkrlnhXctUZyhrieJq.um1sH
OKMs4Gzdo211krGnS0I9BZPdn9.IaOPXc2wG6KSdLdWwICVD83tSF54xLTis
+gRV42nyK7T0p4j6nQyLnAaac4hMuP2a51THYTk9+YazoBR1iQ4IEOsNYQvh
84uMtwmpMagropthukQ4XSAjD+rckO25+r6C0wNzmwXvFIEW0FHd.vJ2KYYf
VRa58AIaTavzGJAUVCnLahBzatn1PQR4p860tOfNofEZ7AK6e09..kRqXlvX
0PskuMeKvS0pG23a6vSY8U+bydz+BM4ODDTwSL9nUScUNIW7eYMCB5GH0Utc
IECzmSO94GfQW.Ye1Fbd6C5vFgyXy9jwXZBtyzLSZqcRsjzE1RcMUjHMpfCA
rIkqjNwH0hzjs5.0TM0zo8WtxpgdkyCgXE7.QlPwDKBEbLxTufASqDL1DiUY
ls7iRMAf8WnLOZceHE+HMktjNPPHpoY.glTbhOsxtJs6K.L.AX5ZXvAxHNdL
DfcZJdLH4Xnyfjh4ZOSIKDi.PygQMeaZJ6cSylZDMw7mUx5C97ke8unOHUwK
VwbZU8RLsh5O3GwICeT1Du2l8HNAP0EyWBPxoEffyB.YHccBgp5oaJw6voEZ
PyhoN5xAX1hE629iAq1mlpr1wQMFHhi7Z0zUUIPaZgM7TqdUT5h8ZS4Kophz
0Xgsw45zkK5wXsJW5Bqfotm+xixubCTqowJBJ0GJ.inM..OspW.ISq9E+pAo
YgNgIK065VzxHHchUNy589.cqzXH5moXT4Zbjn6tY2r5mAYSKZ9KcCGqo8Vc
oeD1MH83DarvWLL+b.ogTLEoqlIHSVtcigddv.AyDpWkYIG2KPWhmUuGNb6C
5H.1dN7.t.3oeCHNtG3xudlvRHV2rEU6nxukwxiMCwyhkG0223rh4CQOx.eC
imvdwyyie0N9NcHCctCow.M5a3LH6Na3lYWeV+MbevIvyx3cEIapNUyusZiu
mcmGq8XMfikI6zG5k8L3bmdXvychqyc7M2TWSK3HtSu8l7fAM4g2TSd8NDNN
4ENO4WmrbalRYyR1RDkDRNX2DfGJIBSBNROplQ0nmLSt8PA1XfBPlHDB4XSh
AAYghRk9qFdlfAmE+Qt43Bcetqz310I+IOBInCOoPTph1kAkL6ovHNXsQ03y
zSPtqnf716IHaPhhtwl7TWm7i6buQrYsJIM0TPMqJwx28Xdzxj5dKqwsY9I7
P42jnLzSZaEC5nLlZdkT.vxl0W7V9NPU80AIvvT.Bw.0GkXeUsR344+Nttuh
nMOVF.V0KbzMtks4YayxqBOsPrrpLN2rHaai5qtpv1CLhjdLM6gnzxnMpJD1
5N7jNFESWewl9bQo4qdU2sWUBjGJJi8Ws2O4JS03jpNYDyGcTLGZR.dJmjx1
F7kp+6W+J0ueaTZPOMlgiUsAr4rlADl474g9LojFPlsh8QNIcLbq5KEUv.bH
UHD5b7skHsZLCVbJXxWoTfRUMLBoqlDH9wJKguWovoekpKsNbI1zTLlvmonI
KA.psnX7ONRkl949oXeheDcWRrEFcJ41NAJdot5dCcKGJdosp24Nh6ghG11f
upHqa9y5jx0kDQQyVQlfx9TOYIJaALDtUdgrrk19SIKwOkrD+TxR3mH63ax1
nDLTXZYFazU8ziYOQQVs2nyIf3EIODmtKL.r7qCdkxpwfO2D9LU2UyHMp0rN
9rxasEMaqzUa85nQ5F+oT9VbDUieuVh0t3k1HpQivqiR+W9uyUX6qBZBtWN1
ZaoVLjt2KBz4aKTNs.7rkiF1zoERwg.lfoaFZ2b4mgGyLC2Nxc3IDG2XGnIo
+yyrTtzzFwGZVWscZ+RSB174e1J3uvQpQkMt5x2jIvAg8FDR14v+UbZZ16dI
7xgd3vgd5MfbwZ66nDKZ23YbkKVW5ftPpMkBFYS8IwS+38zrc9f3o95n.LDA
m6QQkUAmkg8fQDmYAW2xju0nIDUKPt4BIZgNjaa3XeAhBs8qTATXZtWpOH0j
HSUcLiSr4x5G.cOQqMx56VqljIMvje5HQ9oiD4p73xt3zdJFY0OSDFMjRgHs
WvnWQgZabb3OU3yB6Xc+LUuNvLWU1wy0idq7ZQ6yMG7dkGNdoG01K6H313f1
viqS7Fvorw7wgp7ZkFOKcnJuwjnPc8gE0jXS32ZaG6ZJ8i6W+P2E4l59LudA
66lr7cUuVBUMV19cw62NvZiH2GGY0ebegNTa+yYo6W2c4BTfCEbAigZVBlsp
O6MJINwKEJtLyxt21QEP6HZBSX1hRdrJ7RneZWn33TOTAa+LnFPcFuQJ3Un9
AfVkuIyQYrkyF+Mwz1.8gdpadMwhZsQ.xEVHaK6mM2eQkz1VIR3dnZB1Y68Q
PggBLmqqnYH7wB24kt4d2s3mgPjHlZnfi08cPpsJ3eSAEdPoul8Eqd.CIn5j
a0J.JTpFfb.QtzVckvGZ2Yqgu+wMeweb0pNYHfvPkYTPnMTxDTFfItOf628j
EPOr6vthn7h96..BLLT6.AcUKtl9rbzrsAw0zW66.Mx11IEufDRXRIuILTx8
OKvfGZTJ6hS0E2XP29QnNVvHgHDky4lNAwU4Gg97m.18tpy0zN362eB0W+57
USowf1ofc6OA6W6uKOtVWE3iHWKH7PHBEsrmcYpgy5fSUoGBzb5YrqUgrt27
c.lHJX9hILK+CAnt66B00NqtEh19U9XqRBd.DKiViBqtIj6zdfYWSGvTuQh8
uloezZ7SSUSDq5c+dcBt1caDiIwgRDFHKaarX.moalmhNiLPy782UqpwMqsS
Lg3XGs0kSP35cbeGGAgoghSw5+oeEjIXZ+M28mFcUSfVO3fdN2fV+d1qjWe.
qpNklYgKutt12Vb4ROnH9uSmB5+oZ0KuV8GIiEhYDSZ2iHpWC4RFtpHn6K0v
ultzdGtFaabz22miwZrhqEprD7mJQ880z41GVTy2BEy+fU17kdvQRZp3n0a+
fyOEp0GXXcdBjseX+drSU.Hduu5UKErTvQHiC3lrTw1s5QMaW8dqe5AtBsW2
FsINsy9PhPsFk..z3Z4Pot6VqKOfRdnTYxDRa7DmnTfUTOmiq8b27Wv9XuGQ
24Zs7ZF8yJtyEe+ilKLz92AP58G+3ZZtyDvPnI.MXDPUCL3Ze5eFCAKUJCbt
+XK2UT6luOvdila6bVK1p.FrGIrnJBqJmRejvhXK1XNPS0zH7Igjh6AWV8Xb
gKMtTD.erOEJN5sl4rQEdEbX533o6lRdClK0BTKbU2p4zE9vQcIWs1zyIqR8
5XKa..wyNEC6eolwiXItbZv7c.cdVP7IaVfDNWkH.fZdaOO98ZI18Z8Il6yL
tKyLJa5mXLWlXmBrSwDi5zDiz6D6j5ABDAMZ9p1GVweXBjwSFo1eyYYMAQjF
0qlAsnv1f.GHZ4sDt4ljpcQnkuyiqUnKqUcKZZXKUBmFJJsGDqyi.Djg0EgN
jND+NzNpNLt+VeBmj0vmdFGgiBAGLmih0Hjb3nOMoROGaJktbQExebbOh7BW
VfB4fWeJ0EHG7Bph4ffr0Py5q6iiO6qO9Us9T5CcX8IXvP7AmoWMtGWeNsWH
WL8bNLmIrfS+DC5DEwfjkJffP4giYhgCERLS2Y6Ex5TDGF2iTDNA7PIavj75
C1nZAZTBFp6.0zx254kDzCKoFOynMWRT+ujtI0t1QvdNlYNowmfL8SLhSSL7
7Lw5WV2L7nD6DhM8lvcJVbwSrSkzPfgvx3eRKggfwLtNjupKTsZb+I2g6jBs
BvjC7bgySroUeAN2YaSFlYl.fLjdHPgsGCqTXcmVy2gLAIG2z7yKsXno2mlo
krviK4RStoUpNYFxiKYm1Olymd9Bm1ziO8RJ4P2MMdZ4XY.OYzd6FmO8FsSc
RHNa5Eh61DCIuFfGpDDHvRno39i3g3CohZ03dD3cZSpS4LbvOb0VGH.JDwvD
nd8wwgZglTz4GGxHg.AhyM4XBOTVkgcGF2y3AbLjAbJfPvGevVOAtPjiDBUi
6wEnSaKPmdM6oTm8HLZP.eMJnFdDlylTOBSwNu9lVfGKb6XGnCUF.hFJNDKG
XiVPDa.sz56X7i9Q0Lj+dT33JFL8pffch6DSm9IFcrHRF6YFxocnoSu+hQtw
vO8tp.g3tMyXyvTi41TiLCSMp6nFbhmZD2lZ3Y.0bxgcnYgMvMFT.XvAQfVy
cshdTaF4.IByNcm7VBprFfoLvhV9V+soGxI+.BgWikLXoRKdFipSJAc3UwPR
Af2w30zGCq69p.IbhTGCAbicFLCRZ.twNClA1Y.1syhSNCSM3XwNO9SMfaSM
5s8TaZ2UC5X75ImdU6d1eyyYAAbFlZNobGTHmgolaGQLWbaO0lZ1.xXE9Ci9
TywfI6FdpIldm4COMDgN2T6rpDC86TC0+TCNSSMb+SMvLL0DtKxkNwzZCX2.
1DO0XtO03S7TyMakDhYfVysCo77w+oGmZtcJkmOTS73TyorEX5smxpPAo2YF
ZllYN3SI9LM0f2jSMraxaghA6SIaENvjsZXaiZqrYIT+MPfIxZnD68JJGwet
QAhcS6T7b7rvMeUfGbTSfvGeVf.1pfB29qluyVEBzwRb0sqGxmONPi0Zd7mZ
tsyEdFj0gcamKL91cpMCdZvsSdyEYci+TidqtguaGUicALn.LQpiDQcwlybF
Cbn8P0O4cF4Qbfn5j1MC4Q4QtcFKWx9gLZkPUH.Fh.L.hX15iWs0mKCid1v9
DNf9BNfxZvAn80M3lCNbR3lbvQdBDKMD7BD8PV7hklzZskQTZNcRl9VNhGW3
P2i2wAIDn1CPYoBgFsCa7FacaFaKKDMdiRjt8cnZAmnWyZHGQhYYSD2rZDOX
d0ZOjvGZRbVM4q+F6SjZwPkYDe9jvsPeDCtUeR.QjQ3QgU08luiXK66GBXsS
dG2xgY1907Ne+PxA1kYvi6P9Xk.fmQZNWHNQR8gQ7If6lWJwyvwoAcSUR3bL
0.9hV.YqrzbQs5yAVy40xHRxozKki3S5Em2yXParWO5XpELMPLuw9C1w83xC
HbtfvLwmpFvQF0YPQB2hmG4L3hL.ZjT.e7mYtwHwF9lIBk.DHiqs2gwrAjGx
FXdm7VpoT4FHr8I0SdGDXMkFWUCZMC4SVOmieuKmyqrLaEsc6aiy2U9UamS2
sN56rUAY9812mrw9d627c4w5V8dVsSx4tn7EOkTDunXetsVh8dVYK08t0YKi
y2r2zpGgpQJaOgmzmKKAoic8dc6n30l1N+a9CGqG1mzcK+aOuvE+rdaXUke1
d4pFR3I05YhRiKSAVVIoEYK5xpWnE2Bq0hFOoCSRIRcMnsQGlTfvTS0dFb5m
6B5pjmoMPd1R3r5SzZcatd6V79Czis1aNOoub1jFt5wySwoaUPd7aRidHNsp
ljdlGOmzzQaXci9ZG9ZUj1eUdRiRyrtV+03IEsDmZ6UGaEoizxzV3U+5z8w8
sDaokohgbFwzyTYUzIR8P9alZpqiWvTsq5T93OKOoP15FQyy5TsWZWp0GKEz
G2KES6OTWA+u.RGMAMvHKiJQPpYJC8F+3wYJ51Ylp+jpe8+CEEBF8
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Comment: oh sorry jit.xfade has an attrui with 0 or 1

Comment: done. and can you halp me with a delay by the bpm-output. It shoud stay a while bei 1 or 0 and not switching each milisecond.

Comment: haw can i switch cams from umenu with the signal gain ? has someone a solution? and a visualisation switching works just in one direction. Has anyone a solution?